# Rails Amazon S3 Paperclip/s3-swf-upload-plugin Associating attached files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

```
Rails 3.0.5
gem 's3_swf_upload', :git => 'git://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'awk-sdk'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

This is a "is it possible and how hard is it" question. I had a requirement to take in video submission to a website and store them on Amazon S3. Originally I was going to do this via paperclip. However, some one made me aware that we may eat up all our dinos since the file would first be uploaded to our app on heroku first.

Instead I went with the GEM s3-swf-upload-plugin. This is supposed to by pass our server and upload using javascript and flash. (If I am wrong on this please let me know but so far it seems to work as expected.) However, as far as I can tell I can't rename the file with out a fair bit of javascript and I don't think I can collect the URL of the file to link in my object.

What I would like to do: After the file is uploaded and before I save my object I would like to go out to S3 find the file, use paperclip to move/rename it (Using it's useful `:path => ":class/:id/:filename"`) and then assigning the typical paperclip attributes so that I can link to the video in my object.

I have search around a bit today (I admit I have not search as long as I usually do before I come here but my time to get this done is limited) and I all can find is how to set it up normally. The s3-swf-upload-plugin has something which I think may be doing exactly what I need but I don't understand it enough to fit it into my code. https://gist.github.com/575842

If the Gist above is what I need does any one mind explaining what the important part do so I might understand and modify it appropriately? If it is not what I need is there something out there that would help? Thank you all for any help you can provide.